# Laravel - MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$results = DB::selectRaw("idEvent, name, latitude, longitude, dateStart, dateEnd, timeStart, timeEnd,
                             ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                               cos( radians( latitude ) )
                               * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                               ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                               sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                             ) AS distance", [$latitude], [$longitude], [$latitude])
            ->where('active', '1')
            ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
            ->orderBy("distance")
            ->get();
```

I found this query that was the same i wanted to use but with Eloquent, but i'm having

> MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw'.

- Is selectRaw the right one to make raw queries but with a little bit of Eloquent ?
- Is DB something I have to create or I can let this as it is ?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved**

```
$results= DB::table('events')
                            ->select(DB::raw('name,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) )) AS distance'))
                            ->addBinding($latitude, 'select')
                            ->addBinding($longitude, 'select')
                            ->addBinding($latitude, 'select')
                            ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
                            ->orderBy("distance")
                            ->get();


        return Response::json($users);
```

I stopped using selectRaw and used addBinding to insert parameters in my query.

Comment: i am getting error as Call to undefined function radians()